# Cannot bind to properties outside Data Context

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my application I have a two **TreeView** objects that are bound to the same data.
I made a user control for the Tree which is called TreeView and looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Views.TreeControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:MyApp.Model"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyApp.Converters">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:EnumToPicConverter x:Key="Converter"></converters:EnumToPicConverter>
    <!--Control colors.-->
    <Style x:Key="MyTreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=(model:TreeNode.IsExpanded), Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Style>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:TreeNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildListNodes}">
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEqual}" Value="false">
             <Setter  Property="TreeViewItem.Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=EntityType,Converter={StaticResource Converter}}" />
            <TextBlock Margin="5,0" Text="{Binding ItemName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding RootNode}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyTreeViewItemStyle}" />
```

Now, In my main window, I use it in the following way:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:MyApp.Model"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyApp.Converters"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:TreeViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<DockPanel>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="LoadRow">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <views:DbChooser Path="{Binding Path1}" ReloadCommand="{Binding LoadFileACommand}"  Grid.Column="0"/>
        <views:DbChooser Path="{Binding Path2}" ReloadCommand="{Binding LoadFileBCommand}"  Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <views:TreeControl  Grid.Column="0" ItemName="{Binding Name1}"/>
        <views:TreeControl  Grid.Column="1" ItemName="{Binding Name2}"/>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Problem is that:
The **DataContext** is "viewModel:TreeViewModel" , but I want to bind each treeViewItem's Textblock content to a different property of "model:TreeNode"  (which is the type of class of the TreeNodeItem holds..)
And in the main window it says "Cannot resolve property "Name1" in data context of type 'MyApp.ViewModels.TreeViewModel' .
I tried various different options and read few posts here in StackOverFlow but couldn't find a solution..

Thanks for any help.

edit, few clarifications:
 1. TreeControl just wraps WPF TreeView (you can see the code is pasted..)
 2. The DataContext of The MainWindow is TreeViewModel, it is a class that holds the Root Node of the tree (of type TreeNode) and few other properties I use. The Property that I want to "send" to the TreeControl is a property of type TreeNode, which is the type of the TreeViewItems

Another edit:
In other words, what I want to accomplish is that:
To "tell" to the first TreeControl " Please put in the text block of each TreeNodeItem the content of the the property 'Name1' "
And to "tell" the second TreeControl "Please put in the text block of each TreeNodeItem the content of the property 'Name2' "

Comment: First, to make sure: **TreeView** is still the default [WPF TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.aspx), the user control you made is just **TreeControl**?

Second, which ViewModel is where in as a DataContext from your explanation. Maybe Snoop or a different WPF Visual Tree Explorer could help you there, maybe show exactly what DataContext is set where.

Comment: 1.For your first question: Yes, TreeControl just wraps it (you can see the code is pasted..)
2.What other options for trees do I have in WPF that can be helpful? and why would it be different? I read few articles and didn't encounter one..
3. The DataContext of The MainWindow is TreeViewModel, it is a class that holds the Root Node of the tree (of type TreeNode) and few other properties I use.
The Property that I want to "send" to the TreeControl is a property of type TreeNode, which is the type of the TreeViewItems

Comment: Just as information, it would be best to add helpful information directly to the question.

**Edit** So, every TreeControl you create has the same ItemsSource no matter what you do? In my opinion it would be better to create a dependency property in TreeControl and bind the specific ItemsSource you want to the tree, and then use it in TreeControl, this way you switch around dependency, and that shouldn't happen in WPF and MVVM this way.

Comment: Ok, I'm still new here, I'll add my last comments to the question. Thanks

Comment: Ok. There are several problems, but to your first one, the error you show, with Name1, doesn't have anything to do with your TreeView Problem, it's entirely separate, it means that your MainWindow ViewModel probably doesn't have the Property "Name1", or if it does, it's not public.

Comment: It doesn't suppose to have it, because ViewModel just holds the Root Node and Name1 is a property of TreeNode which is the type of the TreeViewItem.

I added in my original post another edit which explains in more 'human' words what i'm trying to accomplish...

Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I don't know where your TreeViewItem is actually stored. What is your RootNode? What Type is it? The way Binding works is that if you do not specify where to bind to, it uses the DataContext. ItemName="{Binding Name1}" means that it looks into the DataContext, TreeViewModel, and looks for a property named "Name1" there. Where is the TreeNode in reference to the DataContext?

Comment: TreeViewItem is type of **TreeNode**. My RootNode is stored in the **ViewModel** (and also of course of type TreeNode). I understand that this is what it does, I just want to tell the first control fill in the textbox the content of **Name1** (which is a property of TreeNode) and the second control the content of **Name2**.

Comment: If Name1 is a property of TreeNode, then you need to specify WHICH TreeNode you mean. For example, you want to use the Name1 of RootNode and pass it to the first TreeControl, use it like that: `ItemName="{Binding RootNode.Name1}"`. If it's TreeViewItem you need to reference to that, but as I don't know which TreeViewItem you actually mean I can't help you there.

Comment: To make sure, With TreeViewItem, do you mean in MainWindow you want to bind to dynamic child elements of TreeControl?

Comment: I don't want to pass RootNode.name1, I want that each Node of the Tree of the first tree will present the property (it's own property "Name1" and each Node of the Tree of the second tree will present the property "Name2" . 
It doesn't have anything to do with the RootNode

Comment: Which means you want to bind to child elements. [Thats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24199898/cannot-bind-to-properties-outside-data-context?noredirect=1#comment37363412_24199898) [problematic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983258/wpf-style-binding-to-child-property-via-elementname). For one, you should do that in TreeControl, not in MainWindow. Also, look at the links I posted. If you need access to children, it will be problematic, maybe they help.

Comment: I think i am miss explaining myself, i'll try again.
There are Two TreeViews that are Wrapped by a Control.

The **Type** of each Node in the Tree is from **TreeNode** type, this type holds the properties : **Name1**, **Name2** .

I want to be able to tell each node of the first tree to present the content of its Name1 property, and each node of the second item to present the content of its Name2 property

Comment: Then the ItemName binding in MainWindow is misleading?

Comment: You want to tell your first TreeControl "use only name1 property", you tell your second TreeControl "only use name2", then you need a property that holds either "Name1" or "Name2" as string, or as type, and in a trigger, like the DataTrigger you already used, set the TextBox.Text Property. Would that solve what you want?

Comment: I have a property Name1 and name2 as a string in TreeNode class (which is the type of each Tree Node.. ). 
But yes, what you say what you say sounds like what I need...

Comment: And btw, yes, The ItemName binding is missleading and I removed it from the code..sorry about that..it was just a desperate try of me to fix it.

Comment: Can't help you more than telling you that a datatrigger might be a good way to go there, sorry. You need to check which Template is the right one for your purpose, maybe it's HierarchicalDataTemplate already, Didn't work much with TreeView.

Comment: Best would be to formulate your question again with knowing exactly what you need it to be, as we found out here now.

Comment: You mean like a whole new question and delete this one?

Comment: Well, that depends. For example, you know that depending on a certain dependency property you have in "TreeControl", you need to show a specific part of your Item, which is in my opinion best solved with DataTrigger and Setter, but in my opinion that doesn't fit the question "Cannot bind to properties outside Data Context" anymore. People might not read it and answer properly. You can also change pretty much the entire question (put the edit on top, keep the rest in there to let people know the history)

Comment: Okay I will do it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not try to answer but perhaps give you some hints to debug.

You can use "DataContextChanged" event on most xaml tag to make sure you get the DataContext you expect.

If you have the expected DataContext but got warning in xaml. You could use:

```
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
```

and set:

```
<AnyTagThatHasDataContext d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=youDataContextObject}">
```

That will help to design your window/UserControl